# prep string array for strlen

Tags: c, arrays

I have a string array that is declared like this:

```
char *strs[MAX_STRINGS];
```

I add values incrementally to the array like this:

```
char buffer [MAX_LENGTH];
buffer = someFunctionThatReturnsAStringPointer();
strs[i] = malloc(sizeof(buffer)+1);
strcpy(strs[i],buffer);
```

I need to loop through array values that get added, stopping when I reach an index with no value, so strlen should work, but it keeps segfaulting whenever I hit an index that hasn't been set:

```
while(strlen(strs[i])!=0) //segfaults when it gets to an unset index
```

How do I initilize the strs array so that it doesn't segfault with strlen?

I tried `memset(strs,0,MAX_STRINGS);` but it messed a lot of things up (the strings were replaced with gibberish) and still segfaulted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably u can set all Pointers to `NULL` initially

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS; i++)
    strs[i] = NULL;
```

And check for

```
while (strs[i] != NULL)
```

or just

```
while (strs[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
char buffer [MAX_LENGTH];
buffer = someFunctionThatReturnsAStringPointer();
```

You should change it to one of the two options below (preferably the second one).

Option #1:

```
char* buffer;
buffer = someFunctionThatReturnsAStringPointer();
```

Option #2:

```
char buffer [MAX_LENGTH];
someFunctionThatCopiesIntoBuffer(buffer);
```

As to your question, you can use `memset(strs,0,MAX_STRINGS)`, or simply iterate the `strs` array and set each entry to 0. But instead of testing `strlen(strs[i])!=0`, you should test `strs[i]!=0`.